# Is there a default output channel if DSL flow ends with endpoin?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

The last element in the code for the following DSL flow is Service Activator (`.handle` method).
Is there a default output direct channel to which I can subscribe here? If I understand things correctly, the output channel must be present[image]

I know I can add `.channel("name")` at the end but the question is what if it's not written explicitly.
Here is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class QueueChannelResearch {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lambdaFlow() {
        return f -> f.channel(c -> c.queue(50))
            .handle(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(QueueChannelResearch.class, args);

        MessageChannel inputChannel = ctx.getBean("lambdaFlow.input", MessageChannel.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            inputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("w" + i)
                .build());
        }

        ctx.close();

    }
```

Another question is about `QueueChannel`. The program hangs if comment `handle()` and completes if uncomment it. Does that mean that `handle()` add a default Poller before it?

```
 return f -> f.channel(c -> c.queue(50));
       //         .handle(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't work that way.

Just recall that integration flow is a `filter-pipes` architecture and result of the current step is going to be sent to next one. Since you use `.handle(System.out::println)` there is no output from that `println()` method call therefore nothing is returned to build a Message to sent to the next channel if any. So, the flow stops here. The `void` return  type or `null` returned value is a signal for service activator to stop the flow. Consider your `.handle(System.out::println)` as an `<outbound-channel-adapter>` in the XML configuration.

And yes: there is no any default channels, unless you define one via `replyChannel` header in advance. But again: your service method must return something valuable.

The output from service activator is *optional*, that's why we didn't introduce extra operator for the Outbound Channel Adapter.

The question about `QueueChannel` would be better to handle in the separate SO thread. There is no default poller unless you declare one as a `PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER`. You might use some library which delcares that one for you.